# Selecting and wrapping all occurences of a certain string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a list of footnote references for an article, I want to select all occurences of "(en)" and wrap them in some  so that I can apply bold style to them as well as a right margin.

How to do that with jQuery ?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant html?  Otherwise we have to assume it's 1 container with some text in it, but the answer is completely different if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

lets say you can get all your data into a string:

```
var myString = $('#footnotes').html();
```

Since you don't need regex you can split into an array and rejoin.. ex:

```
var newString = myString.split("(en)").join("<span class='en-element'>(en)</span>");
$('#footnotes').html(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex to find the "(en)"'s, and then using string.replace to replace them with the content you want.

I know when to use regex but am not too familiar with it's sintaxys, so sorry for not providing the exact code, take a look at this post in which they tried to do the same but finding 
 and replacing it with \n

[jQuery javascript regex Replace <br> with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959415/jquery-javascript-regex-replace-br-with-n)