# Copy div HTML to textarea but keep line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a questionnaire application and one of the features is that the user can click on a question and and edit it. The problem I am having is converting a `<br />` tag into a line break that my textarea will understand.

The save code looks as follows:

```
$('#questions').append("<div>"+$('textarea[name="question"]').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />')+"</div");
```

This works perfectly! The code to convert it back looks like this:

```
$('textarea[name="question"]').val($('#questions').eq(1).html().replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n"));
```

but for some reason the textarea will not accept the new lines and just bundles all of the text together.

How can I convert `<br />` back into a new line feed that my textarea will understand?

Comment: Maybe [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959455/983992) helps

Comment: Hm... '\n' works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FpUFk/

Comment: try \r\n instead of just \n ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('textarea[name="question"]').val($('#questions').eq(1).html().replace(/\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*/g,"\n"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Evrvz/1/)

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted it to do! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the `<br>'s` into HTML encoded newlines.

`&#10;` Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return. This way you are actually parsing the new line ("\n") rather than displaying it as text.

[New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)