# Formatted HTML data in Kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I have a Kendo Grid created in jquery with following code:

Kendo Grid:

```
$('#divFolderNotes').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: data
        batch: true,
        columns: [
               { field: "Text", title: "Note Text" },
               { field: "CreatedByDisplayName", width: '190px', title: "Created By" },
               { field: "CreatedDateTime", width: '190px', title: "Created Datetime" },
                 ],
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        height: 250,
        selectable: "row",
        autoSync: true,
        editable: true,// "inline",
        navigatable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
    })
```

The problem:

First column **Note Text** will be having values which will be containing HTML formatted data.

For a better idea below is an example:

Right Now the data is displayed as :

```
First Name : Nitin <br/> Second Name : Rawat
```

But I want the data to be displayed as :

```
First Name : Nitin
Second Name : Rawat
```

Also , Note Text column will be edited through inline editing so during editing mode also I want the data to be displayed as :

```
First Name : Nitin
Second Name : Rawat
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, there the column "Note Text" has the value `First Name : Nitin <br/> Second Name : Rawat`?

Comment: Yes but for every row it will be having different values which can or can not contain br or other tags.

Comment: Ok. I found a solution, see below.

Answer (score 42):

Set the `encoded` attribute of the column to false to disable automatic HTML encoding.

From the [doc page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.encoded):

> If set to true the column value will be HTML-encoded before it is
>   displayed. If set to false the column value will be displayed as is.
>   By default the column value is HTML-encoded.

Changed code:

```
$('#divFolderNotes').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: data
        batch: true,
        columns: [
               { field: "Text", title: "Note Text", encoded: false },  #<------ Edit Here
               { field: "CreatedByDisplayName", width: '190px', title: "Created By" },
               { field: "CreatedDateTime", width: '190px', title: "Created Datetime" },
                 ],
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        height: 250,
        selectable: "row",
        autoSync: true,
        editable: true,// "inline",
        navigatable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
    })
```

**EDIT:** Since the line break should be preserved when editing, maybe you should just replace the `<br />` tags with a line break character. That way it will show as an actual line break in form fields. Here is an example: [jQuery javascript regex Replace <br> with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959415/jquery-javascript-regex-replace-br-with-n)

It might be better to do this when the user submits the data initially, but, if that isn't an option you can replace it in JS when displaying the data.

Comment: Hey Jonathan Thanks for answering , It solves the displaying problem but while editing, it again shows those br tags.

Comment: Are you using an form field or textarea? Unless you are using a WYSIWYG editor field, or similar the browser is never going to render HTML in your text field.

Comment: I think you would be best off to replace the `<br>` with `\n`. That way new lines will render in a browser's form field.

Comment: @NitinRawat, I added more details on both.

Comment: Hey Jonathon thanks for your reply: but it will be a big hack of changing the <br/> to \n as then I have to convert it back for the updation purpose as I have to save the HTML string

Comment: If your the edit field isn't capable of rendering HTML, then I don't think there is any other way to do it. What happens to the value when a user edits the field, and then presses enter? Does it add in a line break, add in a `<br/>` or does it end the inline editing?

Comment: So, if you change it so that pressing enter adds a line break or `<br/>` how do you expect the user to end the inline edit? Click a button? Hello edge cases!

Comment: What I want is that on editing or on adding a new row , in both cases the Note text cell on encountering a enter should start a new line but when saving into the database ,on click at any other cell, the data should contain the <br/> tags for every enter that is made.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50119/discussion-between-nitin-rawat-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 3):

You can try kendo template.

for these Please Try Following links

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid

hope this will help.